# Why wont my onTap method work, How do I make my onTap method lead to another page?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an app with flutter and in my application I made an hidden drawer by putting 2 pages in a Stack widget and when I click on the menu icon, the homepage gets an offset and the drawer screen becomes visible. On the drawerscreen I have 2 selfmade buttons which are supposede to lead you to another page.

My drawer in my homepage is setup with an AnimatedContainer>Listview>Column>Container as in the code below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:paws_up/components/buttons/animated_button.dart';
import 'package:paws_up/components/buttons/category_button.dart';
import 'package:paws_up/pages/product_overview_page.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  double xOffset = 0;
  double yOffset = 0;
  double scaleFactor = 1;
  bool isDrawerOpen = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      transform: Matrix4.translationValues(xOffset, yOffset, 0)
        ..scale(scaleFactor),
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 20,
                ),
                height: 70,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    isDrawerOpen
                        ? IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                xOffset = 0;
                                yOffset = 0;
                                scaleFactor = 1;
                                isDrawerOpen = false;
                              });
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.chevron_left_rounded,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                            ),
                          )
                        : IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                xOffset = 230;
                                yOffset = 150;
                                scaleFactor = 0.6;
                                isDrawerOpen = true;
                              });
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.menu,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                            ),
                          ),
                    const Text(
                      'PawsUp',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xff363636),
                          fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 24),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications_outlined,
                              color: Color(0xff363636)),
                          onPressed: () {
                            // do something
                          },
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.person_outline_rounded,
                              color: Color(0xff363636)),
                          onPressed: () {
                            // do something
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 30,
                  horizontal: 20,
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 247, 247, 247),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.filter,
                              color: Color(0xff5891AC)),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          'Search..',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xffCAC9C9),
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: const Color(0xff5891AC),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      ),
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: const Icon(
                          FontAwesomeIcons.magnifyingGlass,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                height: 140,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: const Color(0xffD5E5F4),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                      top: 50,
                      left: 135,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(0),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(0),
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(15)),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'images/Banner_photo.jpg',
                          height: 90.0,
                          width: 190.0,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 0, 8),
                            child: Text(
                              'Join our animal loving community',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: AnimatedButton(
                              height: 40,
                              width: 100,
                              text: 'Join Now',
                              textColor: const Color(0xffD5E5F4),
                              buttonColor: Colors.white,
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          const ProductOverviewPage()),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 30,
                  horizontal: 20,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const Text(
                          'Pet Categories',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xff363636),
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Spacer(),
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: const Text(
                            'More Categroies',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xff5891AC), fontFamily: 'Ubuntu'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                      child: ListView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        children: const [
                          CategoryButton(
                            text: 'Cat',
                            buttonColor: Colors.white,
                            selectedButtonColor: Color(0xff5891AC),
                            contentColor: Color(0xff363636),
                            selectedContentColor: Colors.white,
                            isSelected: false,
                            icon: FontAwesomeIcons.cat,
                          ),
                          CategoryButton(
                            text: 'Dog',
                            buttonColor: Colors.white,
                            selectedButtonColor: Color(0xff5891AC),
                            contentColor: Color(0xff363636),
                            selectedContentColor: Colors.white,
                            isSelected: false,
                            icon: FontAwesomeIcons.dog,
                          ),
                          CategoryButton(
                            text: 'Fish',
                            buttonColor: Colors.white,
                            selectedButtonColor: Color(0xff5891AC),
                            contentColor: Color(0xff363636),
                            selectedContentColor: Colors.white,
                            isSelected: false,
                            icon: FontAwesomeIcons.fish,
                          ),
                          CategoryButton(
                            text: 'Bird',
                            buttonColor: Colors.white,
                            selectedButtonColor: Color(0xff5891AC),
                            contentColor: Color(0xff363636),
                            selectedContentColor: Colors.white,
                            isSelected: false,
                            icon: FontAwesomeIcons.dove,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 30,
                  horizontal: 20,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const Text(
                          'Adopt Us',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xff363636),
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Spacer(),
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) =>
                                      const ProductOverviewPage()),
                            );
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            'See All',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xff5891AC), fontFamily: 'Ubuntu'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                      child: ListView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        children: const [],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The drawerScreen code is as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:paws_up/components/buttons/drawer_button.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:paws_up/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:paws_up/pages/product_overview_page.dart';

class DrawerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DrawerScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<DrawerScreen> createState() => _DrawerScreenState();
}

class _DrawerScreenState extends State<DrawerScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xffD5E5F4),
      ),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 20,
                horizontal: 20,
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const CircleAvatar(),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: const [
                        Text(
                          'Firstname Lastname',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Location',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              fontSize: 16),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  DrawerButton(
                    text: 'Home',
                    icon: Icons.home,
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  DrawerButton(
                    text: 'Adopt',
                    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.paw,
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => ProductOverviewPage()),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  // DrawerButton(
                  //   text: 'Donate',
                  //   icon: FontAwesomeIcons.circleDollarToSlot,
                  // ),
                  // DrawerButton(
                  //   text: 'Favorites',
                  //   icon: FontAwesomeIcons.solidHeart,
                  // ),
                  // DrawerButton(
                  //   text: 'Messages',
                  //   icon: FontAwesomeIcons.solidEnvelope,
                  // ),
                  // DrawerButton(
                  //   text: 'Profile',
                  //   icon: FontAwesomeIcons.solidUser,
                  // ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 70),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  // DrawerButton(
                  //   text: 'Settings',
                  //   icon: FontAwesomeIcons.gear,
                  // ),
                  // DrawerButton(
                  //   text: 'Log in',
                  //   icon: FontAwesomeIcons.arrowRightToBracket,
                  // ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I think the problem lies in the DrawerButton. It is supposed to lead you to different pages but it doesn't. This is my DrawerButton code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DrawerButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final IconData icon;

  DrawerButton({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.icon,
    required Null Function() onTap,
  });

  @override
  _DrawerButtonState createState() => _DrawerButtonState();
}

class _DrawerButtonState extends State<DrawerButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  late AnimationController _controller;
  late double _scale;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      lowerBound: 0.0,
      upperBound: 0.1,
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _scale = 1 - _controller.value;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: _onTapDown,
      onTapUp: _onTapUp,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Transform.scale(
            scale: _scale,
            child: _DrawerButtonUi,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get _DrawerButtonUi => Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(
              widget.icon,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Text(
                widget.text,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );



  void _onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
    _controller.forward();
  }

  void _onTapUp(TapUpDetails details) {
    _controller.reverse();
  }
}
```

I thought maybe it had something to do with the stack widget I have in the gesturedetector of my DrawerButton. I have tried navigator.of(context).push instead of navigator.push, but that does not seem to make a difference.

But I am not quite sure how I can build that widget differently, keep the animation and have the navigator push work.

Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a widget variable in order to access on state class.

```dart
class DrawerButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final IconData icon;
  final VoidCallback onTap; //this will be used
  const DrawerButton({
    super.key,
    required this.onTap,
```

And will be called on

```dart
  void _onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
    _controller.forward();
    widget.onTap();
  }
```